# Total Amount detection from Firebase vision text

Tags: android, firebase, machine-learning, google-vision, firebase-mlkit

I want to detect the total amount from Google Firebase Vision kit.

What I did ?

I have all the text from the vision recognizer but unable to find a perfect algorithm to get the total amount in any language.

What I want ?

I have Bitmap/file and I want to get the total amount from that file. The text is already detected.

And I want it Offline only.

Answer (score 4):

ML Kit is quite good at detecting text in an image, and extracting it from there. But it doesn't have any built-in "total amount" detection.

We needed this same functionality, for a [talk we did at Google I/O building an expense tracker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q), and it turned out to be surprisingly tricky. We ended up using this very simple function, which finds the maximum number in the detected text:

```
exports.findTotal = function findTotal(detections) {
  const regex = '^[$]?\s*(\\d+[\\.,]\\d{2})$';
  const amounts = detections
    .filter(text => text.description.match(regex))
    .map(text => text.description.match(regex)[1])
    .map(text => text.replace(',', '.'))
    .map(text => Number(text))
    .concat([0.0]);
  return Math.max.apply(null, amounts);
}
```

Note though that, even in our limited testing, this didn't always work great. So your mileage may vary.

Full code for the project is on Github: https://github.com/puf/zero-to-app-expenses.

Comment: Hey Frank, I guess you wanted to paste the actual link for the talk, but you ended up pasting the code again in-text - have a look...

Comment: Oops. Fixed. Thanks for catching/

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the response but this code will fail when there are discounts applied on the amount. As the total amount will be less than the maximum amount.